# How to configure WSO2 to integrate with SAML 1.1 Service provider running in Weblogic 10.0

Tags: weblogic-10.x, wso2-identity-server

We have couple of applications running on Weblogic 10.0 and would like to enable single sign on between them. We are planning to use WSO2 Identity server for this purpose. Most of the documentation I came across provides details on how to integrate with SAML 2.0. However, Weblogic 10.0 only supports SAML 1.1, and hence would like to know the steps to configure a SAML 1.1 service provider in WSO2 Identity server.

Comment: Have you looked at something like http://biemond.blogspot.com/2009/05/sso-with-weblogic-103-and-saml.html ? Your question is not detailed enough for someone to answer here

Comment: Can you please clarify what kind of detail might help to answer this question? I can add more details accordingly.